# Unable to delete a windows folder?

Tags: windows, explorer

There are quite a lot of suggestions to be found whilst searching but none had worked for us, (most likely because the folder name appeared to be appended with a (weird?) blank character which we also could not rename or delete). The folder properties security tab showed no information only errors. Various tools provided no info on the folder for us.

Answer (score 0):

In file explorer navigate to the parent folder

Open a command prompt: `Dir /X`

in our case the problem folder then ended with ~1

```
ren shortname~1
del shortname~1
```